# why featured product not updated in postmeta table in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

Where in the database can I find that a product is marked "featured"?
I have marked 4 products as featured but I have yet to find out how to retrieve this information from any the database tables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.0 featured products are marked as featured by being given the `featured` term that WooCommerce creates in the `product_visibility` taxonomy.

But to tell if a product is featured, instead of checking the terms directly or using `get_post_meta()` (which wouldn't work anymore anyway), use the `get_featured()` method of `WC_Product`:

```
$product_id = 1;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$featured = $product->get_featured();
```

Comment: veeery nice . veeery good

Answer (score 1):

Featured Products Loop in WooCommerce 3

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => 'featured',
                ),
            ),
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```